# Pandas read_csv has correct headers but column names is None

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm reading a simple csv file with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('spread.csv', header=0)
df
```

[image: df output]

However trying to list the column names I get None:

```
list(df.columns.names)
```

The output is simply None. Which doesn't seem inline with the output above or the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Am I doing something wrong or what's happening here?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to just get the A, B, C, D column names you only need to do

```
print(df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not assign the `columns` `names` , that is why when you call `names` the default output show as `[None]`

```
df.columns.names
Out[934]: FrozenList([None])
list(df.columns.names)
Out[935]: [None]

df.columns.names=['SOMETHING']
df
Out[931]:
SOMETHING  id  A  B
0           1  1  2
1           2  2  3
df.columns.names
Out[932]: FrozenList(['SOMETHING'])
list(df.columns.names)
Out[937]: ['SOMETHING']
```

If you just want the dataframe columns name

```
list(df)
```

---

```
Data Input 

data = '''\
id  A B
1   1 2
2   2 3 '''


import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
```